# Create a JSON format using loops

Tags: python, loops, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm in the process of creating a Table for AWS DynamoDB. All the documentation on how to use the required JSON format is demonstrated entirely manually... in my case, I want to create several tables, each with several columns - it seems inefficient to do this manually when I know my column headers and their data types...

The boto3 website has a guide with the following snippet:

```
# Get the service resource.
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

# Create the DynamoDB table.
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='users',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'username',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'last_name',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'username',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'last_name',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
    }
)
```

Now I'm wondering, of course if you had hundreds of columns/AttributeTypes in your data, you wouldn't want to sit there typing it all in. How can I automate this process with a loop? I have a general idea but I'm coming from Java and I'm not quite proficient to think of the solution in this case.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT:

I worded this question *horribly*, and had gotten too bogged down in the documentation to understand what I was asking about. I wanted a solution for automating the addition of data to a DynamoDB table using loops. I explain in my answer below.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly do you see the manual part that you want to automate? Where is the JSON that you keep referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unbeknownst to me at the time - the snippet shown in my question is only about defining the key schema - i.e. your primary/ composite keys. What I wanted to do was add actual data to the table - and the examples of this were all done manually on the boto3 documentation.

To answer my own question: first, you obviously need to create and define the key schema - and that's no time at all to do manually using the template shown in the question.

Note that Boto3 will not allow float values... my solution was to change them into `str` types. Boto3 recommends using `Decimal`, but `Decimal(str(value))` would not work, as it was being passed as string `Decimal(value)` for some reason (can anyone explain?):
[Passing a Decimal(str(value)) to a dictionary for raw value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966507/passing-a-decimalstrvalue-to-a-dictionary-for-raw-value)

This is how I used pandas to import data from excel, and then automated putting that data into my table:

```
#panda reads the excel document to extract df
df = pd.read_excel(fileRoute,dtype=object)

#the column headers are allocated to the keys variable
keys= df.columns.values

#create a dynamodb instance and link it to an existing table in dynamodb
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(name)

#batch_writer() allows the addition of many items at once to the table
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    dfvalues = df.values

    #loop through values to generate dictionaries for every row in table
    for sublist in dfvalues:
        dicts = {}
        for ind, value in enumerate(sublist):
            if type(value) is float:
                if math.isnan(value): #you might want to avoid 'NaN' types
                    continue
                value = str(value) #convert float values to str
            dicts[headings[ind]] = value
        batch.put_item(
            Item=dicts #add item to dynamoDB table
        )
```