# Passing a Decimal(str(value)) to a dictionary for raw value

Tags: python, dictionary, decimal, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm needing to pass values to a dictionary as class 'decimal.Decimal', and the following keeps happening:

```
from decimal import *

transaction_amount = 100.03
transaction_amount = Decimal(str(transaction_amount))
item = {
'transaction_amount': transaction_amount
}

print(item)
```

Results:

```
{'transaction_amount': Decimal('100.03')}
```

How do I attain the raw 100.03 result, rather than Decimal('100.03')?

This is what I want the dictionary to have saved:

```
{'transaction_amount': 100.03)}
```

When I do:

```
print(transaction_amount)
```

The result is as expected:

```
100.03
```

So where am I going wrong?

I don't see any reason why this question should be downvoted.

Comment: Use `float()` instead

Comment: I'm needing to add the dictionary as items to a DynamoDB table - I don't think boto3 allows float types...

Answer (score 0):

When you ask python to print an object, it'll print the textual representation of that object.

Here your variable item is a dictionnary, so its representation is as follow:

`{ key: value [, repeat]}`

If you want the value inside your dictionnary, you would have to go at the specified key like so :

`print(item[transaction_amount])`

So basically, your code was fine and your use of decimal too, but you weren't testing it the good way. ;) Happens a lot.

**Edit:**
It's worth noting that, since what you are getting within the dictionnary object is `Decimal(100.03)`, even when printing the value of the key-value pair as I showed previously, you won't get a pure 100.03, but probably `Decimal(100.03)`.

I'll search some documentation as to how to get the string. 
Welp apparently no, it should work like a charm.

**Edit: I didn't get the question (which has been edited since then) right.**
However because of the extended conversation in the comment section, it'll remain here.

Comment: That's exactly the problem! Why is the dictionary object coming up as `Decimal(100.03)` rather than `100.03`? Surely if printing the item before it is added to the dictionary returns `100.03`, it should be the same for the dictionary item?

Comment: My guess is that printing dictionnary is usually done in debugging and such, so python made it that it would always represent the internal data structure of your objects more than a simple, beautiful value. While print of values is usually done for the end-user to read what's printed, so they made it less technical and more relevant. In other word, str(dictionnary) probably doesn't call str(item) and str(keys)

Comment: Also sorry I guess I didn't understand what you meant. xD

Comment: I'm passing these dictionaries as items to a table in DynamoDB, where the `transaction_amount` column is specified to be of a number datatype. When I add the item to my table, it fails and gives me an error - as the `transaction_amount` values are being passed as str rather than as decimal it seems.

Comment: I believe we would need to see more of the code, as the issue is probably rather in the day the data is inserted. Python's print never has anything to do with the actual data it is printing, and shouldn't have any effect over the way you can use them. ---

However, it appears DynamoDB (did some research) takes string when you want to insert decimal. So you would have to do transaction_amount = str(100.03) without using using Decimals in the python code.

Comment: See this link for further documentation on what people ended up doing: 
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/665